# Variable assignment within React classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I want to assign a variable within a react component class like so...

```
class Something extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.someMethod=this.someMetho.bind(this)
****const variable = this.props.something==='this.state.something'?this.props.something:this.props.something.filter(according to some criteria);****
    }
someMethod(){
bla bla
}
render(){
***variable***.map((item, index)=>
{return <htmlTag> some stuff dependent on mapping<close/> }
}
}
```

obviously, this doesnt work, React will accept such assignments as valid code but will not let you access the variable for some reason (so it seems, at least according to my console(log) tests). How would you do something like this WITHOUT refactoring as a function and where should the variable go? Is there a better way to do this, again WITHOUT writing a function and using hooks? the starred variable indicates what i want to do, would not need to be at that part of the function, but what it does need to do is run some test based on the internal state of the class.
A variable assignment with ternary that filters something (in this case an array) according to the class state.

I am fully aware that what I have written amounts to bad practice, but the details of this are irrelevant. I know what I personally would write in the circumstance, but that is not really the question.

If this is in any way unclear what I am asking, it is simply about using variables within react classes, where they can be declared, where not and how I might do something similar to the above.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

A variable declared in the `constructor` function won't be available in the `render` function. They are different functions.

If you want to store data for use in other methods on the component, then store it in the state.

There is an [example in the introductory tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#making-an-interactive-component).

Answer (score 0):

For React class components, state must be saved in `this.state`. See this link for more details: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html